# Java: How do I print out in descending order the values of a list of objects' properties?

Tags: java

Edit: I've got it now thanks everyone!

What I'm supposed to be doing is printing the total hours for all the employees in descending order, as in Employee C: 100 hours, Employee A: 70, Employee B: 50, etc.

I have everything set up to take in input for everything and now i have the objects with their total hour values I just can't figure out any way to print the highest total hours object. What I have so far will print the highest ones as it hits them but it skips any that weren't the highest when it gets to them.

Every question I've seen about something similar using something called Comparators which I can't seem to get working, maybe I'm just not understanding how to get them to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Employee {
    public String name;
    public int[] hours = new int[7];
    public int totalHours;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number of employees");
        int a = input.nextInt();
        Employee[] employeeNames = new Employee[a];
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            employeeNames[i] = new Employee();
        }
        for (Employee b : employeeNames) {
            System.out.println("Enter name of employees");
            b.setName(input.next());
            System.out.println("Enter hours");
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                b.setHours(i, input.nextInt());
            }
        }

        for (Employee b : employeeNames) {
            b.setTotalHours();
            System.out.print("Employee: " + b.getName() + " ");
            System.out.println(b.getHours());
        }
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < employeeNames.length; i++) {

            for (int j = 1; j < employeeNames.length;j++) {
                if (employeeNames[i].getTotalHours() >= employeeNames[j].getTotalHours()) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if(count >= employeeNames.length - i){
                System.out.println(employeeNames[i].getTotalHours());
            }
        }

    }

    private void setName(String a) {
        name = a;
    }

    private String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    private void setHours(int i, int a) {
        hours[i] = a;
    }

    private String getHours() {
        return Arrays.toString(hours);
    }

    private void setTotalHours() {
        for (int i = 0; i < hours.length; i++) {
            totalHours += hours[i];
        }
    }

    private int getTotalHours() {
        return totalHours;
    }

}
```

Comment: Make your `Employee` class implement [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), put them in a `List` and use `Collections.sort()` afterwards.

Comment: Ok... I'll have to look into that, not too clear on what that mean. Just put implement Comparable right after `public class Employee`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an easy example to make you understand SORITNG OF OBJECTS :

public class Employee implements Comparable {

```
String eid;
String ename;
int esal;

public Employee(String eid, String ename, int esal) {
    super();
    this.eid = eid;
    this.ename = ename;
    this.esal = esal;
}

public String getEid() {
    return eid;
}

public String getEname() {
    return ename;
}

public int getEsal() {
    return esal;
}

@Override
public  int compareTo(Object o) {

    Employee obj=(Employee)o;

    if (this.getEsal() < obj.getEsal()){
        return -1;
    }else if (this.getEsal() > obj.getEsal()){
        return 1;
    }else
        return 0;
```

}

}

Now lets sort Employees as per Salary:

import java.util.Collections;
public class MainClass {

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    ArrayList<Employee> al=new ArrayList<Employee>();

    Employee obj=new Employee("e01", "Shan", 222);
    Employee obj1=new Employee("e02", "viv", 600);
    Employee obj2=new Employee("e00", "arun", 100);

    al.add(obj);
    al.add(obj1);
    al.add(obj2);

    Collections.sort(al);

    Iterator i=al.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()){
        Employee o1=(Employee)i.next();
        System.out.println("Sal: "+o1.getEsal());
    }

}
```

}

It will give you output:

```
Sal: 100
Sal: 222
Sal: 600
```

I hope now you get the logic behind comparable.If suppose you need to reverse the pattern of sorting then simply modify as below

```
 @Override
public  int compareTo(Object o) {

    Employee obj=(Employee)o;

    if (this.getEsal() > obj.getEsal()){
        return -1;
    }else if (this.getEsal() < obj.getEsal()){
        return 1;
    }else
        return 0;
```

}

and new Output will be:

```
Sal: 600
Sal: 222
Sal: 100
```

Comment: Oh wow thank you so much! I got it to work! I had to make it display each person's name and change how the objects got added to the array list so it works with a user inputted amount.

I sort of understand how the comparable works, I'm still a little foggy on `this.` but I have never used it before so now that it works I'm gonna spend some time figuring it out.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Comparators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) or implements [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) interface

Implementing Comparable interface should be something like:

```
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {

....

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Employee employee){
        return this.totalHours - employee.totalHours;
    }

}
```

Then you only have to sort:

```
Arrays.sort(employeeNames);
```

This code has not been tested.

Comment: In compareTo, you should use `Integer.compare()`; not that this will happen here, but it will take of possible overflows/negative numbers etc

Answer (score 1):

Java has a static .sort() method in both the Collections and Arrays class that allows you to accomplish what you are after.  The .sort() method takes a Collection or Array, depending on which you are sorting and a Comparator.

A Comparator is an object that controls how the Array or Collection will be sorted by indicating when an any given object of the type you are interested in is greater than, equal to, or less than another object of that type.  The Comparator interface has a method called compare() that takes two objects (any arbitrary objects from the Array or Collection to be sorted) and return 0 if the objects are equal, < 0 if the first object is less than the second object, and > 0 if the first object is greater than the second object.  The .sort() method then uses an efficient sorting algorithm to order the Collection or Array based on the Comparator's notion of ordering.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html for more details about comparators.

You probably want to define a Comparator that subtracts one employees hours from the other to determine the ordering:

```
Arrays.sort(employeeNames, new Comparator<Employee>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Employee firstEmployee, Employee secondEmployee) {
        return secondEmployee.getTotalHours() - firstEmployee.getTotalHours();
    }       
});
```

After executing this code, your array employeeNames will be ordered in descending order by the total number of hours.  You can then iterate over the list and print them as necessary.